# How to query inside a populated object in MongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having troubles querying inside a populated document with Mongoose. What I need here is that it returns all the posts made by an author. I tried these two methods, the first one does not return anything, and the second one returns an error. How could I fix this?

```
Post.find({
    author: {
        fullName: { $regex: req.params.author, $options: "-i" },
    },
})
```

```
Post.find({
    author.fullName: { $regex: req.params.author, $options: "-i" }
})
```

Model for Post:

```
const postSchema = new Schema(
    {
        [...rest of the model]

        author: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
    }
)
```

Model for author:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        [...rest of the model]
        
        fullName: String,
    },
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What error does the second one throw ?

Comment: This: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`

Comment: Try wrapping the field name in quotes? `"author.fullName"`

Comment: Not working, it just returns an empty array